# Is it possible to leave blank spaces in matplotlib's pcolormesh plots?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, colormap

I'm displaying some data using `matplotlib.pyplot.pcolormesh` in python, and I want to leave blank spaces where there are missing data points.

Suppose I've collected data for `x` values 0 to 10, and y values 0 to 10, but not every such value. At present, I initialize my data storage array using `np.zeros((11,11))`, then use a `for` loop to change the values of that array to the data value if I have the data for that point.

That leaves me with a bunch of data plus some zeros in an array. When I plot this, it is impossible to distinguish between points that have no data and points which have data with small values.

Is it possible to have missing data points clearly distinct from non-missing data points? For example, in the code below I want the squares at `(3,1)`, `(5,7)`, and `(8,8)` colored but the rest of the squares white.

I've tried initializing my data storage array with `np.empty((11,11))` and `np.full((11,11),np.nan)` as well, but they both produce the same output as `np.zeros`. Here's the code below:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data_storage = np.zeros((11,11))
collected_data = [[3, 1, 45.2], [5, 7, 23.9], [8, 8, 78.4]

for data in collected_data:
    x_coord = data[0]
    y_coord = data[1]
    value = data[2]
    data_storage[y_coord,x_coord] = value

all_x_values = np.linspace(0,10,11)
all_y_values = np.linspace(0,10,11)

plt.pcolormesh(all_x_values, all_y_values, data_storage)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to change all zeros to `NaN`, which would make the corresponding cells transparent.

Please note that the x and y values for `pcolormesh` are for the grid points, not for the centers, so you need one value more in each dimension (11 cells, 12 cell borders). This allows to create color meshes with unequal cell sizes. If you want the ticks to be nicely in the center of the cells, you can put the cell borders at the halves.

(In the code below the `for`loop has been written more concise).

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data_storage = np.zeros((11, 11))
collected_data = [[3, 1, 45.2], [5, 7, 23.9], [8, 8, 78.4]]

for x_coord, y_coord, value in collected_data:
    data_storage[y_coord, x_coord] = value

all_x_values = np.arange(0, 12) - 0.5
all_y_values = np.arange(0, 12) - 0.5

plt.pcolormesh(all_x_values, all_y_values, np.where(data_storage == 0, np.nan, data_storage))
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(1))
plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(1))
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

An alternative approach could be to create a colormap, set an ['under' color](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.Colormap.html#matplotlib.colors.Colormap.set_under) and set `vmin` to a value slightly larger than 0. Optionally, the 'under' color can be visualized in the colorbar with `extend='min'`.

```
from copy import copy
my_cmap = copy(plt.cm.get_cmap('viridis'))
my_cmap.set_under('lightgrey')
plt.pcolormesh(all_x_values, all_y_values, data_storage, cmap=my_cmap, vmin=0.000001)
plt.colorbar(extend='min', extendrect=True)
```